# Logistic regression, loss function and KL divergence

Tags: regression, logistic, kullback-leibler

In decision theory, a loss function signature is supposed to be

```
output space * output space -> error
```

There seems to be many different definition of 'the logistic loss' on the web

- Some define it as 'the negative of the log likelihood' [boyd](http://www.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/l1_logistic_reg.pdf) : this is clearly not a loss function in the decision theory point of view
- Some define it as a function of R * [K ] -> R [upen](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis520/wiki/index.php?n=Recitations.SVMPrep#toc5) : same pb wih the domain

---

So would the correct ***decision theory** loss* be expressed in term of distribution ?

That is:

- given an x, I get back a distribution over the K cases, *given by the softmax* equation in the case of the logistic regression (output space = distributions)
- my loss function is the KL distance between this distribution and the observed one  (signature = distributions * distribution -> R)

PS: R is for the real number and [K] is the discrete set of integer from 1 to K

Comment: An explanation of your notation would help people understand what you're asking.  What are "R" and "[K]"?  Note, too, that there is no such thing as a "correct" loss: that is something adopted beforehand by the decision maker.

Comment: indeed but there is a 'logistic loss' which you will find in the literature. (and it so happens that it in the legendre conjugate of the softmax function which yields to simple updates I think)

Comment: What, then, is your question?  Is it about what kind of mathematical object any loss function should be, or is it about what specifically a "logistic loss" is?

Comment: the reported loss functions, for which I provide a link, can not be losses in the decision theory sense. hence the question with an interrogation point.